# Swig[C->Python]: How to handle input or output function arguments which are primitive types?

Tags: python, c, swig

for example, I have

my_types.h

```
typedef uint16_t my_type_1;
typedef uint8_t my_type_2;
```

my_types.c

```
int my_func(my_type_1 * arg1, my_type_2 * arg2, my_type_3 *arg3)
{
    *args3 = *arg1 + *arg2;
    return 0;
}
```

how do I define the interface file to have this wrapped to python?

Comment: You have a few typos in your question - there is no `my_type_3` typedef and you have args3 instead of arg3 in the definition of `my_func`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you *don't* have a declaration of `my_func` in my_types.h as well then your interface can become:

```
%module test

%{
#include "my_types.h"
%}

%include <stdint.i>

%include "my_types.h"

%apply uint16_t *INPUT { my_type_1 * arg1 };
%apply uint8_t *INPUT { my_type_2 * arg2 };
%apply uint16_t *OUTPUT { my_type_1 *arg3 };

int my_func(my_type_1 * arg1, my_type_2 * arg2, my_type_1 *arg3);
```

This is sufficient to allow you to use it as follows:

```
import test

print test.my_func(100, 50)[1]
```

Your "real" return is position 0 in the tuple, the first OUTPUT is at position 1.